# Trying to redirect on successful registration

Tags: reactjs

This is in a react component, I'm trying to redirect back to my homepage on successful signup onSubmit , but if there is an error, stay on the current form. Here is the relevant code snippets. This is my first question I've ever posted...I'm not sure why my code snippets aren't formatted correctly...any help would be great, thanks everyone!

signupForm.js

```
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addMerchant({ 
      variables: {
        name: values.name, 
        email: checkUnique(values.email, values.password, e),
        password: checkPassword(values.password, values.confirmPassword, e)}})
      .then()
      .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
    history.push('/');
  }

   const checkPassword = (password, confirmPassword, e) => {
    if(password === confirmPassword) {
      return password;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("merchant-signup-form").reset();
      history.location.pathname=`${window.location.origin}/signup`
      return alert("Problem Creating Account");
    }
  };

   const checkUnique = (email, password, e) => {
    if (email !== password) {
      return email;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      history.location.pathname=`${window.location.origin}/signup`
      document.getElementById("merchant-signup-form").reset();
      return alert("Password cannot be your email");
    }
  };
```

Comment: What is wrong/not working?

Comment: Did you add props to function parameter? and then `props.history.push('/');`

Comment: @Saddy the page is pushing to my homepage no matter what, error or success, I am pushed to home with the history.push('/'). The problem is on error, I don't want to be redirected away from the page, only on success

Comment: @ramilabbaszade Hi, I haven't tried that, but the function is working, I am getting pushed to home, I just don't want it to work when there is an error with signup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reason you're still being sent to the root:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addMerchant({ 
       variables: {
         name: values.name, 
         email: checkUnique(values.email, values.password, e),
         password: checkPassword(values.password, values.confirmPassword, e)}})
    .then()
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
     });
     history.push('/'); //You're still sending to "/" after catching.
}
```

A catch block will NOT end execution of code that comes after it. All the code will run just fine, since the error was "handled" by the catch block.

To fix it, just put the redirect inside the `then`block, which will only run if the request is successful.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addMerchant({ 
       variables: {
         name: values.name, 
         email: checkUnique(values.email, values.password, e),
         password: checkPassword(values.password, values.confirmPassword, e)}})
    .then(() => {
        history.push('/'); //Only redirect if success.
     })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
     });
.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just did that and it works. I tried it before without the arrow function and that was my earlier mistake, cheers!